# using QtApplication in netbeans

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans

I have created a project using QtApplication in netbeans and I need to call a function in that project from a different project which is a normal C/C++ project.Can any body tell me how to do???thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried QProcess? It's used to start external programs and communicate with t

Comment: that is a really good suggestion.I am also thinking to create the dynamic library of one project and then use it in the other.I am gonna check it within few days because of exams and will let you know the results that which one is most effective.Thanks for your quick and valuable reply.Highly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried both options and the one in which you create the library and call it in other function works great in this scenario.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Last few days I was trying to integrate ns3 with Qt but now I have successfully integrated them.I am providing the solution so that it can be helpful to save time:

In order to integrate ns3 and Qt, I;
1)-created the dynamic library of the code written in Qt using IDE netbeans.

2)-In order to link and use that library I place the header file in the build/project folder so that I can use it easily.After that to link the dynamic library in ns3, I added following lines in the script file:

module.ccflags=['-wall','-O3']

module.lib=['QDynLib']

module.libpath=['/home/a/Documents/ns-allinone-3.16/ns-3.16/src/propagation/QDynLib/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86']

module.linkflag=['-g']

module.rpath=['/home/a/Documents/ns-allinone-3.16/ns-3.16/src/propagation/QDynLib/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86']

Here,I used the absolute path to locate the dynamic library.

**Location of the Dynamic library;**
/home/a/Documents/ns-allinone-3.16/ns-3.16/src/propagation/QDynLib/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/

**Name of the library File:**
libQDynLib.so

to find the explanation and detail of these python commands please refer to the link:
http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_15/single.html#_c_and_c_projects